# Dynamics of parallel manipulator

Tags: force, dynamics, manipulator

My task is to apply forces to control 3-dof parallel manipulator. Forces are applied to linear  actuators, friction is neglected.  End-effector of a robot is supposed to follow generated path; for this example, let it be a simple circle. So far I have made a simplified 3d model of robot and calculated inverse kinematics.

[image: 3D model of robot]

Promoter of my engineering work don't really know how to do this, but he said that calculating forward dynamics is too complex and i shouldn't go that way. Could you tell me what will be the easiest way to go?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you trying to convert a desired end effector position to the desired positions of the 3 actuators?